# No colour printing on 18.04 after upgrade with hp officejet 6500 e709n

Tags: printing, hp, pdf, adobe, okular

After upgrading to 18.04 i encounter troubles when trying to print pdfs in colour. When I open a pdf in okular and try to print it, the output is always b/w. Further I am missing the printer quality option in the printer dialogue. There is no chance to set the quality and b/w or colour option. 
What I have tried so far:

- Reinstall the printer via the kde dialogue and command line (also with different ppds (hpjis and hpcups).
- Trying to print via Adobe Reader DC and Wine (which worked on 16.04 perfectly)
- Setting the defaults setting of the printer in the kde dialogue and cups

There was no change in this. Interestingly this happens only when i try to print pdf in okular/adobe reader DC: In libreoffice writer printing works with no problems!

Any suggestions what I could do?